# For each row in a table select the most recent date in another table joined by a value

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, group-by, multiple-tables

I have the 2 following tables:

```
          Table1                                              Table2        
ID      IP         Timestamp                   IP             Login           User
1      10.2.4.8    02/04/2016 9.10             10.2.4.8   01/04/2016 8.20     Green   
2      10.2.4.8    02/04/2016 13.50            10.2.4.8   01/04/2016 8.50     Blue 
3      10.20.3.5   02/04/2016 13.59            10.2.4.8   02/04/2016 9.20     Red     
4      10.2.4.8    03/04/2016 10:25            10.20.3.5  04/04/2016 11:25    Blue    
5      10.20.3.5   04/04/2016 11:25            10.20.3.5  01/04/2016 10:25    Yellow
```

I want to match the timestamp in Table1 with the closest previous login from Table2 where the IP are the same, in order to get the user who did the login. So the result should be like this:

```
ID      IP         Timestamp            User
1      10.2.4.8    02/04/2016 9.10      Blue
2      10.2.4.8    02/04/2016 13.50     Red 
3      10.20.3.5   02/04/2016 13.59     Yellow     
4      10.2.4.8    03/04/2016 10:25     Red    
5      10.20.3.5   04/04/2016 11:25     Blue
```

I'm using SQL.Thanks for any help

The solution I came up with is this:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.IP, T2.user, MAX (T2.Login) AS Ultimo_Timestamp, T1.timestamp FROM Table2 T2, Table1 T1
WHERE T2.IP = T1.IP
AND T2.Login < T1.timestamp
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.IP, T2.user, T1.timestamp
ORDER BY T1.ID;
```

I am not sure if it is correct, and if there are any better solution. Thanks

Comment: You're storing timestamps under the appropriate data type, right? Good, so show us what you tried.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, i came up with this code, but I'm really not sure if it is ok. : SELECT T1.ID, T1.IP, T2.user, MAX (T2.Login) AS Ultimo_Timestamp, T1.timestamp FROM Table2 T2, Table1 T1
WHERE T2.IP = T1.IP
AND T2.Login < T1.timestamp
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.IP, T2.user, T1.timestamp
ORDER BY T1.ID;

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using a `correlated subquery` with `top`:

```
select t.id, t.ip, t.timestamp, 
   (select top 1 t2.user
   from table2 as t2
   where t.ip = t2.ip 
     and t2.timestamp < t.timestamp  
   order by t2.timestamp desc) as user
from table1 as t
```

Comment: Why do you post answers on questions that show zero effort?

Comment: Hi @sgeddes, thanks , it looks correct but I get a "Subquery can only return 1 record." error. I'm using access, is it the solution I updated in the question also correct? thanks again